# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Tags: gradle, java-8, jaxb, fastlane, gradlew

I have a fastlane setup in my project, which fails with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException` at the `gradle(task: 'assemble', build_type: 'internal')` command.

I've tried `./gradlew assembleInternal` and it works fine. Also I have included

`compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
 }`

As I unterstand databinding is not compatible from Java JDK 9, but since I'm using 1.8 it should work well. My guess is for some reason fastlane is not using my gradle wrapper from the project directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the other `jdk` versions from `Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` solved the problem for me